# How to populate a textbox with the appropriate information related to the item selected from a drop down list in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, select, mysqli

I'm creating a form where it allows a user to enter in the number of product rows they would like to have in the form. Then with the corresponding rows, you can select the Product with the Product_ID & Product_Name from a Drop Down List. With the selected item, it should pull the Product_Cost from the table and populate the Unit Price textbox. I can't seem to get the textbox to populate with the correct data. My if statement `if (isset($_POST['product' . $i])){` doesn't seem to be working properly, it runs as if the statement were false. I'm trying to say "If a select box has an option selected, take the option selected and find it's corresponding row in the database and take the price found in that row for that product and populate the unit price textbox."

```
<? require_once("connect_to_DB.php"); //inserts contents of this file here ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Order Form</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
    <body>

        <? 

        connectDB();

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
        $sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT emp_id, emp_fname, emp_lname FROM employee";
        $sql3 = "SELECT DISTINCT status_id FROM salesorder ORDER BY status_id asc";
        $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM salesorder ORDER BY order_id desc";

        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("SQL error: " . mysqli_error());
        $result2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql2) or die("SQL error: " . mysqli_error());
        $result3 = mysqli_query($db, $sql3) or die("SQL error: " . mysqli_error());
        $result4 = mysqli_query($db, $sql4) or die("SQL error: " . mysqli_error());

        //This is for the options in the product list box
        $options = '<option value="selectProduct">Select Product</option>';

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)){

            $options .= '<option value="' . $row[0] . '">' . $row[0] . ' - ' . $row[2] . '</option>';
        }

        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
        $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
        $row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4);

        ?>

    <div id="order-wrap">
        <form method="post" action="example.php">
            <table class="orderInfo"><br>
                <tr>
                    <th class="textCol">Product Rows:</th>
                    <td class="inputCol"><input type="text" name="rows"></td>
                    <td><input class="update" type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
                    <td class="inputCol"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form><!-- Order Rows -->
        <form class="orderform" action ="order-report.php"  METHOD = "post">
            <h2>Order Form</h2>

            </table>

        <!-- Where the product rows input show go ??? -->
        <table class="bottomTable">
            <tr>
                <th class="textCol">Product</th>
                <th class="textCol">Quantity</th>
                <th class="textCol">Unit Price</th>
                <th class="textCol">Total Price</th>
            </tr>

        <?
            if (isset($_POST['update']))
            {
                //Execute this code if the update button is clicked.
                $num = $_POST['rows'];

                for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++) { ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="inputCol2">
                            <select name="'product<?= $i ?>'">
                                <?
                                    echo $options;
                                 ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inputCol2"><input type="text" name="'quantity<?= $i ?>'" ></td>

                        <? if (isset($_POST['product' . $i])){ ?>

                            <td class="inputCol2"><input type="text" name="'unit<?= $i ?>'" value="<?= $row[3] ?>" placeholder="$" ></td>

                        <? } else { ?>

                            <td class="inputCol2"><input type="text" name="'unit<?= $i ?>'" value="" placeholder="$"></td>

                        <? } ?>

                        <td class="inputCol2"><input type="text" name="'total<?= $i ?>'" placeholder="$"></td>
                    </tr>
                <? } ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="textCol"></td>
                        <td class="textCol"></td>
                        <td class="textCol">Total Order:</td>
                        <td class="inputCol2"><input type="text" name="totalfinal" placeholder="$"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="orderSubmit"/> 
            </form>
            <? } else {?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="textCol"></td>
                        <td class="textCol"></td>
                        <td class="textCol">Total Order:</td>
                        <td class="inputCol2">$<input type="text" name="totalfinal"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="orderSubmit"/> 
            </form>

            <? } ?>
       <?
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            mysqli_free_result($result2);
            mysqli_free_result($result3);
            mysqli_free_result($result4);
            mysqli_close($db);
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, you want to be using an `onchange` trigger on the first select box to dynamically populate or choose something in another select box.  You would do this with JS/jQuery.

Comment: I realize that this would be much easier with Javascript & jQuery, but I'm learning to use PHP to work with the database. I'm trying to see how I would go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be some syntax errors in there, for instance:

```
<select name="'product<?= $i ?>'">
    <?
        echo $options;
     ?>
</select>
```

There seems to be several instances where this type of quotation marks are used - I think they ought to be more like:

```
<select name="product<?= $i ?>">
    <?
        echo $options;
     ?>
</select>
```

Also, in a few places you are not using the correct opening tag for the php blocks though someone might point out different. Generally they ought to be:

```
<?php
    /* statements */
?>
```

or

```
<?="print out this string";?>
```